# MySQL header files not found MySQL-python db

Tags: mysql, django, macos

I've been trying to get Django running on my MAC OS Lion for a while today and have had no success.  I have Python 2.7.1 pre-installed on my MAC.  I have MySQL installed as the packaged that came with XAMPP.  And I've installed Django 1.4.1.

I went ahead and confirmed that django was successfully installed by importing django in terminal via python and everything was fine- no error.

The problem comes whenever I try to build and install the setup.py file in MySQL-python-1.2.3.  When I do:

sudo python setup.py build

in the MySQL-python-1.2.3 directory, I get the error:

```
RE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL
_mysql.c:36:23: error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:38:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:39:26: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:40:20: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:76: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL’
```

(and more errors)...
(ending with...)

```
llvm-gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/powerpc-apple-darwin11-            llvm-gcc-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory
```

lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccShAtAs.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 255**

Further, when I get the same errors when I try to do:

sudo python setup.py install

Comment: Did you install mysqldb? Its a python interface for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL-Python needs MySQL C header files in order to build, however they seem not to be included in the XAMPP default install. [The internet suggests you install the XAMPP development package](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=152611).